# MYSQL Select Query with SUM

Tags: php, sum

```
| campaign_id | catgory_id 
--------------------------
| 1       | xxx         
| 2       | xxx       
| 3       | xxx       
| 4       | yyy      
| 5       | yyy       
| 6       | yyy         
| 7       | yyy
```

I need the following output:

xxx > Total: 3
yyy > Total: 4

Comment: These are basic ones in SQL, just use `group by` and `count`

Comment: That's nice. So go to work.

Comment: Noone will solve your homework assignments here. Rather, read on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Please explain your question in some more detial.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/group_by.php

Comment: You definitely won't get that output using `SUM`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this query. I hope it's will help you.

```
SELECT catgory_id,COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name GROUP BY catgory_id;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very basic in sql . But solution is

```
SELECT catgory_id,COUNT(*) as total FROM tbl_name GROUP BY catgory_id;
```

This will be working fine.